# Missing Azure powershell cmdlet after install

Tags: powershell, azure, module, powershell-cmdlet

Would just like to ask if anyone has encountered this sort of issue? Though I have already installed Azure powershell I am still somehow getting errors regarding `Get-​Azure​Rm​Sql​Server` cmdlet. This confuses me because I am able to run other cmdlets such as `Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase`

```
Get-​Azure​Rm​Sql​Server : The term 'Get-​Azure​Rm​Sql​Server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Tried manually importing the module but it still didn't budge.

```
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.Sql\AzureRM.Sql.psd1'
```

Edit:
After running `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`
The result:

```
 Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                           
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                           
Manifest   3.7.0      Azure                               {Get-AzureAutomationCertificate, Get-AzureAutomationConnection, New-AzureAutomationConnection, Remove-AzureAutomationCon...
```

Comment: could you please run this command to check the version of your azure powershell `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`,?

Comment: Here's the result.

`Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement`

Comment: `ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                           
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                           
Manifest   3.7.0      Azure                               {Get-AzureAutomationCertificate, Get-AzureAutomationConnection, New-AzureAutomationConnection, Remove-AzureAutomationCon...`

Comment: As a workaround, maybe we should uninstall it, and re-install it manually, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Azure PowerShell version is 3.7.0.
I download Azure [PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v3.7.0-March2017/azure-powershell.3.7.0.msi) and install it manually, it work for me.
Maybe you should uninstall this PowerShell first, then re-install it with the download file.

```
PS C:\Users> Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.7.0      Azure                               {Get-AzureAutomationCertificate, Get-AzureAutomationConnec...


PS C:\Users\v-jianye> get-azurermsqlserver

cmdlet Get-AzureRmSqlServer at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
ResourceGroupName:
```

Please try to **re-install** it.

Comment: i'll get back to you if i get a chance to reinstall it as it is in our prod envi as of the moment :( Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CarlArdiente Does it work now? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @CarlArdiente Does it work now, please let me know if you would like further assistance, by the way, if it helps, please don't forget mark is as an answer so that other community members will benefited.

Comment: Hi @Jason Ye - MSFT, i didn't reinstall the Azure cmdlets but for some reason it fixed itself. Maybe it was because I opened it in another fresh (admin) powershell ISE. Sorry for the delay